# A single php file for all forms

Tags: php, mysql

I have four forms on my website sending user input to four different tables in my MySQL database. Is it good practice to put all the queries for those four forms in a single php file?

Currently, I have a different php file for each form. Eg. form-abc.html has a abc.php to communicate with the database, form-def.html has a def.php and so on.

Since the mysqli connection in all these forms is going to be the same, I was wondering if it is possible to call the relevant function/ query from a php file containing all the queries/functions? And if it is possible, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On balance it is not good practice to put the code in a single file, particularly if the four queries are not obviously related in terms of their purpose, but it would also be poor design to have each file containing the code to connect to the database, and also to be hand crafting the query strings.

You should seek to factor out common code to a utility library, with your starting point being to have a single library function that returns a connection to the database. Changing connection details, the name of the database etc. then requires a single change rather than four, and so reducing the chances of a mistake. Your four files should also not *need* to know how to connect to the database, and removing the code achieves that.

Rather than hand crafting the queries, where there is a chance of failing to properly escape data and where you will end up writing more code than is necessary as well as locking yourself to a particular database type, you should aim to have library routines to help with this. PHP has some libraries already, or you could develop your own that are potentially better suited for the job.

Very broadly, you may end up with code such as this:

```
<?php

include_once "db_utils.php";

$db = DB::get_instance();

if (isset($_POST['form_submitted'])) {
  // Validation etc.
  $customers = $db->table('customers');

  $customers->insert(array('name' => $_POST['name'], 'email' => $_POST['email']));
  // ...
}
```

The include would include your database utilities, providing in this case a class called DB, and a table class. get_instance() would be a static method to provide database instance that encapsulates a connection. We'll assume that it knows how to obtain connection information, so not needing that to be provided to the method. The table() method would provide an instance of a database table that would know how to perform operations on a database table. The insert() method on a table instance would take an array of key/value pair data, escape the value of each item and do the insert.

Keeping the queries with the files that need them should in this case ease maintenance.

An alternative approach to your entire site would be to use a framework. In such a case, the business logic, database management and rendering code would be separated, which for non-trivial systems is generally a desirable aspiration. If one cobbles a system together with that in mind in an ad-hoc way, this could quickly lead to an unmaintainable system, with developers struggling to find the relevant code that plays a part in a request, however a framework would impose a structure through naming and layout conventions that would largely alleviate that.

For where you are now though, just aim to identify duplicate code, factor that out, look for some database libraries so that you are not hand crafting queries (if you are right now), and keep your system simple.

Comment: Yes, I am hand-crafting queries, mainly because I don't know anything about 'libraries'. I learned some programming in 2000 and using that basic knowledge to learn and implement with languages that were not even in vogue at that time. That said, I am learning something new each day. I started with php for mysql and then switched to Mysqli for security reasons (my host doesn't support PDO). Though I have no idea what you mean with some of what you said, it gives me pointers to what I need to look for next. Libraries it is then! As for frameworks..that would be after I understand libraries!

Comment: @vinaya It does not particularly matter whether you use Mysqli or PDO, they're just somewhat different APIs: what matters is that you are using parameterized queries. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php